# modulemap in framework or headers in umbrella header are not being imported

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, xcframework

I am converting my framework into an xcframework. Got "Using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported", moved the imported headers from the bridging header into my umbrella header and deleted the bridging header. I have my modulemap pointing to an umbrella header.

```
framework module MySDK {
    umbrella header "MySDK.h"
    
    export *
    module * { export * }
}
```

The umbrella header has all the objc header files I need in Swift files imported. Other Swift files in my framework claim they can't see the files imported in "MySDK.h". "Jump to Definition" on the errors takes me exactly where it should. I have been trying to fix this for weeks with no luck.

Please can anyone help me?

Comment: Try to use dependency managers, for example Cocoapods or SPM. Don't need to do this work manually.

Comment: This is all code in the same framework. My Obj-C classes in MySDK aren't being seen by my Swift files in MySDK.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Dependency manager will configure framework for you.

Comment: @Cy-4AH Can you explain more on what you are suggesting? It seems like massive overkill to create a separate framework just for my objective-c code.